# Docker for non-code deployments?

Tags: docker

I am trying to help a sysadmin group reduce server & service downtime on the projects they manage. Their biggest issue is that they have to take down a service, install upgrade/configure, and then restart it and hope it works.

I have heard that docker is a solution to this problem, but usually from developer circles in the context of deploying their node/python/ruby/c#/java, etc. applications to production.

The group I am trying to help is using vendor software that requires a lot of configuration and management. Can docker still be used in this case? Can we install any random software on a container? Then keep that in a private repository, upgrade versions, etc.?

This is a windows environment if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 2):

Docker excels at stateless applications. You can use it for persistent data style applications, but requires the use of volume commands.

> Can docker still be used in this case?

Yes, but it depends on the application. It should be able to be installed headless, and a couple other things that are pretty specific. (EG: talking to third party servers to get an license can create issues)

> Can we install any random software on a container?

Yes... but: remember that when the container restarts, that software will be gone. It's better to create it as an image, and then deploy it.See my example below.

> Then keep that in a private repository, upgrade versions, etc.?

Yes.

Here is an example pipeline:

Create a Dockerfile for the OS and what steps it takes to install the application. (Should be headless)

Build the image (at this point, it's called an image, not a container)

Test the image locally by creating a local container. This container is what has the configuration data such as environment variables, the volumes for persistent data it needs, etc.

If it satisifies the local developers wants, then you can either:

1. Let your build servers create the image and publish it an internal
   docker registry (best practice)
2. Let your local developer publish it
   to an internal docker registry

At that point, your next level environments can then pull down the image from the docker registry, configure them and create the container.

In short, it will require a lot of elbow grease but is possible.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Do you mind clarifying headless? - Edit: Just did a quick google, so from the command line. Could be more of an interesting problem.

Comment: Yes, that would be a big factor. A lot of legacy apps require GUI installation on windows.

Answer (score 0):

> Can we install any random software on a container?

Generally yes, but you can have many problems with legacy software which was developed to work on bare metal.

- At first it can be persistence problem, but it can be solved using [volumes](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/).
- At second program that working good on full OS can  work not so good in container. Containers have some difference with VM's or bare metal. For example due to missing `init` process some containers have [zombie process](https://blog.phusion.nl/2015/01/20/docker-and-the-pid-1-zombie-reaping-problem/) issue. About others difference you can read [here](http://phusion.github.io/baseimage-docker/)

Docker have big profit for stateless apps, but some heave legacy apps can work not so good inside containers and should be tested good before using it in production.